# Auto-refresh ENSIME error buffer

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

Is there a way I can make ENSIME errors buffer (the one invoked with `C-c C-v e`) to automatically refresh whenever I save my Scala source file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following code after loading of ensime:

```
(add-hook 'ensime-source-buffer-saved-hook 
          'ensime-show-all-errors-and-warnings)
```

Comment: Actually, in my tests this shows the *current* errors aware by SBT. So  if I introduce an error in my code and save, SBT takes 2-3 seconds to figure it out, but ensime has already opened the "error" buffer, which  shows "0 errors, 0 warnings". In plain words, this needs an async notification from SBT when the compilation is completed...